# AS3 Game loop and draw frame

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, frame, render, draw

I am building a game for school in AS3. I made a game loop with a timer so this game can run faster.

```
private var updateTimer:Timer;
updateTimer = new Timer(0);
updateTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, update);
updateTimer.start();

private function update(e:TimerEvent):void {     }
```

This is working, but my teacher did show me a function/command how I can draw/render a frame.

Because of that the frame rate will go up. Unfortunately, I lost that code and I ca'nt find that function anywhere. Does anyone know that function? Yes, I know this way is very unstable.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea, Adobe says in docs: "A delay lower than 20 milliseconds is not recommended. Timer frequency is limited to 60 frames per second, meaning a delay lower than 16.6 milliseconds causes runtime problems." You should imo rather set your frameRate higher and use standart ENTER_FRAME event for your game loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you thinking of [`TimerEvent.updateAfterEvent()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TimerEvent.html#updateAfterEvent%28%29)? This causes Flash to render a new frame immediately independent of the movie frame rate in response to a timer or mouse event.

```
e.updateAfterEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just change the frame rate of a game without messing with timers, you can always use `stage.frameRate` and go from there. So if you want to increase the frame rate, just use `stage.frameRate++;`.